# Merging USGS DEM files in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, dem, error-999999

I'm trying to merge my DEM files into 2 separate files, one will have 4 files and the other will have 3. I've been reading every post from when someone asked this before for over an hour and I'm still having problems. Here's a look at what I'm trying to do:  [image]

I'm having problems using the DEM to raster tool in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop (I keep on getting a 999999 error and haven't been able to locate anything that I'm doing wrong) I'm trying to do that and then use mosaic to new raster (something I found in a previous discussion). Any suggestions or a basic step by step on something better to do would be nice.

Comment: Can you give us the syntax of the DEM to Raster tool? perhaps there's something wrong there.. in the end you want them mosaiced right? The USGS DEM format is a supported raster format http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000000q000000 so perhaps it would be best to construct a mosaic dataset rather than trying to mosaic the tiles.

Comment: Yes, my end goal is to have two files without any seams that I can do one process on all 3/4 pieces and not have to do it on each individual piece, if that is clear. I have also tried using the add rasters to mosaic dataset tool, but it gave me an image with a high and low of 3.4e+38

Comment: Calculate the statistics on the mosaic dataset to get realistic min/max... how does it look in ArcMap with a min/max stretch (edit min/max values to values you're expecting)? It's possible that the NoData value wasn't carried through properly, you may need to set that for each tile.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't matter if it is just the data frame, but looking at the dimensions and orientation of those tiles it looks like you have a projected data frame or data. Have the tiles been projected? You'll need the original geographic tiles. For something small like this I usually just mosaic rasters with the Image Analysis toolbar and export that to a file after confirming it is the output I am looking for. Avoid resampling (or projection) until after the files are mosaiced.

Also, when you get raster outputs that display improperly or report strange statistics, you can sometimes save a lot of frustration by closing all Arc windows, opening Catalog, going to your raster and deleting and rebuilding statistics. This sometimes occurs to me in the moment...usually just not the right moment.